# Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run agvs robot package on Raspberry pi 3 I am getting the above error when I do catkin_make. the details are as follwos. I am using Kinetic version of ROS

```
agv@agv-desktop:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/agv/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/agv/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/agv/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/agv/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/agv/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/agv/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/agv/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/agv/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.4
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 5 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - agvs_control
-- ~~  - agvs_gazebo
-- ~~  - agvs_sim (metapackage)
-- ~~  - agvs_sim_bringup
-- ~~  - agvs_robot_control
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'agvs_control'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(agvs_sim/agvs_control)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'agvs_gazebo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(agvs_sim/agvs_gazebo)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Error at /home/agv/catkin_ws/devel/share/realtime_tools/cmake/realtime_toolsConfig.cmake:106 (message):
  Project 'realtime_tools' specifies
  '/home/agv/catkin_ws/src/realtime_tools/include' as an include dir, which
  is not found.  It does neither exist as an absolute directory nor in
  '/home/agv/catkin_ws/src/realtime_tools//home/agv/catkin_ws/src/realtime_tools/include'.
  Ask the maintainer 'Stuart Glaser <sglaser@willowgarage.com>' to fix it.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/joint_state_controller/cmake/joint_state_controllerConfig.cmake:165 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package)
  agvs_sim/agvs_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/agv/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/agv/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:290: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255641/invoking-%22make-cmake_check_build_system%22-failed/) by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That directory exists in the [realtime_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/realtime_tools) package. Thus I would hazard a guess that your checkout is incomplete or corrupted.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0